# Substract value from dataframe under certain condition and add the rest to the next value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has 3 buildings and the demand of electric vehicles in kW.
Each building can only charge with max 11 kW, so if the demand is higher (eg. 13 kWh) then 13 - 11 = 2 must be added to the value of the next hour.

To make it more clear, the dataframe looks like this, and I want transform it like this:

```
      bd1    bd2    bd3                bd1    bd2    bd3
0     11     9      7            0     11     9      7
1     15     6      14           1     11     6      11
2     8      12     13    ->     2     11     11     11
3     2      0      0            3     3      1      5
...                              ...
8759  8      7      12           8759  8      7      11
```

I can't add the surplus to the last row, so the rest should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some preliminary assignments:

```
max_charge = 11
to_add = np.zeros(len(df.columns), dtype=np.int64)
maxs = to_add + max_charge
result = []
```

Perform forward adjustments to each row:

```
for r in df.values:
    row = r + to_add
    to_add = np.where(row > max_charge, row - max_charge, 0)
    row = np.minimum(row, maxs)
    result.append(row)
```

Combine results and overwrite the last row:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(result), columns=df.columns)
df2.iloc[-1] = df.iloc[-1]
```

Here is what I got at the end:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   bd1  bd2  bd3
0   11    9    7
1   15    6   14
2    8   12   13
3    2    0    0
4    8    7   12

In [7]: df2
Out[7]: 
   bd1  bd2  bd3
0   11    9    7
1   11    6   11
2   11   11   11
3    3    1    5
4    8    7   12
```